# Excel cannot open the file because the file format or file extension is not valid. Verify that file has not been corrupted

Tags: c#, excel

I am trying to export into excel with `xlsx` and `xls`
 format but getting this error when trying to open the file. **Excel cannot open the file** `'tms.xlsx'` because the file format or file extension is not valid. Verify that file has not been corrupted and that the file extension matches the format of the file.

```js
public static void ExportToExcel(object allLists, string fileName, string driverName)
        {
            try
            {

                grid.DataSource = allLists;
                grid.DataBind();
                RowCreated();
                Header(fileName, driverName);
                HttpContext.Current.Response.ClearContent();
                string FileName = String.Format(fileName + "-{0}", DateTime.Now.ToString("dd/MMM/yyyy"));               
                HttpContext.Current.Response.ContentType = "application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.spreadsheetml.sheet";
                HttpContext.Current.Response.AddHeader("content-disposition", "attachment; filename=" + FileName + ".xls");
                StringWriter sw = new StringWriter();
                HtmlTextWriter htw = new HtmlTextWriter(sw);
                //Applying style to grid view header cells


                for (int  i = 0; i < grid.Rows.Count; i++)
                {
                    for (int J = 0; J < grid.HeaderRow.Cells.Count; J++)
                    {
                        if ((grid.Rows[i].Cells[J].Text.Contains("-y@llow")))
                        {
                            grid.Rows[i].Cells[J].BackColor = System.Drawing.Color.FromArgb(255, 255, 179);
                            var val = Convert.ToString(grid.Rows[i].Cells[J].Text);
                            if (val != null && val != "")
                            {
                                if (val.Contains("-y@llow"))
                                {
                                    val = val.Replace("-y@llow", "");
                                    grid.Rows[i].Cells[J].Text =Convert.ToString(val);
                                }
                            }
                        }
                        else if((grid.Rows[i].Cells[J].Text.Contains("-gr@en")))
                           
                        {
                            grid.Rows[i].Cells[J].BackColor = System.Drawing.Color.FromArgb(159, 223, 159);
                            var val =Convert.ToString(grid.Rows[i].Cells[J].Text);
                            if (val != null && val != "")
                            {
                                if (val.Contains("-gr@en"))
                                {
                                    val = val.Replace("-gr@en", "");
                                    grid.Rows[i].Cells[J].Text = Convert.ToString(val);
                                }
                            }
                            
                        }
                    }
                }
                for (int i = 0; i < grid.HeaderRow.Cells.Count; i++)
                {

                    grid.HeaderRow.Cells[i].Style.Add("background-color", "#337ab7");
                    grid.HeaderRow.Cells[i].Style.Add("color", "white");
                  
                }

                grid.RenderControl(htw);
                HttpContext.Current.Response.Write(sw.ToString());
                HttpContext.Current.Response.End();
            }
            catch (Exception)
            {
                //Response.End() will generate exception so, do not throw the exception here.
                //Response.Write(Ex.StackTrace);
            }
        }
```

Comment: Where is the place you creating excel file?

Comment: I write code in c#.

Comment: I generating excel file from c# code.

Comment: where is that part? when you convert that object to response?

Comment: Are you sending an HTML table pretending it's an Excel file?  That used towork but in newer versions of Office there's "protection" against doing that.  Google for "Extension hardening" - e.g. https://jwgoerlich.com/excel-extension-hardening-and-web-applications/

Comment: Oh, wow! That just feels wrong. If you're willing to use some OpenSource library to create your Excel take a look at [SpreadsheetLight](http://spreadsheetlight.com) which is what I use for creating the Excel data. You'll need to check coloring capabilities, though.

Answer (score 0):

Please check content type and extension. You currently have `.xls` and `application/vnd.ms-excel`. The stated `xlsx`requires the respective extension and

```
ContentType = "application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.spreadsheetml.sheet"`
```

To add a bit of context I use this as follows in an controller method that returns an `ActionResult`

```
ActionResult ExportAsExcel(object input)
{
    var fileData = ExcelExport.CreateExcelContent(input);

    if (fileData == null || fileData.Length == 0)
    {
        ViewData["Message"] = "Could not create export file";
        View("Error");
    }

    // File is of type Controller.File
    return File(fileData, "application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.spreadsheetml.sheet", "export.xlsx");
}
```

Comment: Not working this code:ContentType = "application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.spreadsheetml.sheet"`

Comment: this code: HttpContext.Current.Response.AddHeader("content-disposition", "attachment; filename=" + FileName + ".xlsx");
                HttpContext.Current.Response.ContentType = "application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.spreadsheetml.sheet";

Comment: Hm, maybe it is the content then. Please update your question with the respective code as already asked by @cdev